# How to fix this error in jQuery uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: label

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have this function that is called in my jQuery called `updateField` on the blur event. The console returns this error:

> ```
> uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: label
> ```

Where is the problem?  I can't seem to find it.

Below is the HTML code:

```
<li>
    <label for="element_label" class="desc">Field Label</label>
    <textarea class="textarea" id="element_label" onBlur="updateField()"></textarea>
</li>
<li id="prop_element_name" style="display: block;">
    <label for="element_names" class="desc">Field Name</label>
    <select id="element_names" name="element_names" onBlur="updateField()">
        <?php
        if ($master_elements = query("SELECT * FROM master_elements WHERE field_type != 'scrubbed_data' ORDER BY element_label")) {
            foreach ($master_elements as $idx=>$element) {
                echo "<option value=\"{$element['masterid']}\">{$element['element_label']}</option>";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </select>

                    
    <a href="javascript:;" id="new_element_name_lnk" title="New Field Name"><img src="/img/form_builder/add.gif" /></a>
                
</li>
```

and Below is the `updateField` function being called:

```
function updateField(option) {
    if (option) {
        input_id = $("li.current_edit").attr("id").replace(/li_/, "");
        $("li.current_edit :input#masterid_" + input_id).val( option.element_masterid );
        $("li.current_edit :input#type_" + input_id).val( option.element_type );
        $("li.current_edit :input#name_" + input_id).val( option.element_name );
        $("li.current_edit :input#validation_" + input_id).val( option.element_validation );
        $("li.current_edit :input#label_" + input_id).val( option.element_label );
        $("li.current_edit :input#guidelines_" + input_id).val( option.element_guidelines );
        $("li.current_edit :input#size_" + input_id).val( option.element_size );
        $("li.current_edit :input#options_" + input_id).val( option.element_custom_options );
        $("li.current_edit :input#format_" + input_id).val( option.element_format );
        $("li.current_edit :label#title_" + input_id).html(option.element_label);

        display_field_properties();
        updateField();
        return false;
    }
    else {
        input_id = $("li.current_edit").attr("id").replace(/li_/, "");

        inputtype = $("li.current_edit :input#type_" + input_id).val();
        $("li.current_edit :input#type_" + input_id).val(inputtype);

        label = $("#element_properties").find("#element_label").val();
        validation = $("#element_properties").find("#element_validation").val();
        required = $("#element_properties").find("#element_required").attr("checked");

        if (required) {
            $("li.current_edit :input#validation_" + input_id).val('required,' + validation);
            $("li.current_edit :label#title_" + input_id).html(label);
            $("li.current_edit :label#title_" + input_id).append('<font class="required"> *</font>');
        }
        else {
            $("li.current_edit :input#validation_" + input_id).val(validation);
            $("li.current_edit :label#title_" + input_id).html(label);
        }
        $("li.current_edit :input#label_" + input_id).val(label);


        var name = $("#element_properties :input#element_names").val();
        $("li.current_edit :input#name_" + input_id).val(name);
        $("li.current_edit :input#masterid_" + input_id).val(name);

        options = $("#element_properties").find("#element_options").val();
        $("li.current_edit :input#options_" + input_id).val(options);

        guidelines = $("#element_properties").find("#element_guidelines").val();
        $("li.current_edit :input#guidelines_" + input_id).val(guidelines);
        $("li.current_edit div#hint_" + input_id).html(guidelines);

        if (inputtype == "date") {
            // str = format,input
            str = $("#date_format").val() + "|" + $("#date_input_type").val();
            $("li.current_edit :input#format_" + input_id).val( str );
            var str = '<a title="Click to edit. Drag to reorder." onclick="return false;" class="hover_ready" href="#">';
            str = str + '<label id="title_' + input_id + '" class="desc">' + label + '</label>';
            str = str + '<div>';

            if ($("#date_input_type").val() == "select") {
                var dd_options = '<option value="1">1</option>';
                dd_options = dd_options + '<option value="2">2</option>';
                dd_options = dd_options + '<option value="3"> .. </option>';
                dd_options = dd_options + '<option value="31">31</option>';
                var mm_options = '<option value="1">1</option>';
                mm_options = mm_options + '<option value="2">2</option>';
                mm_options = mm_options + '<option value="3"> .. </option>';
                mm_options = mm_options + '<option value="12">12</option>';
                var d = new Date();
                curyear = d.getFullYear();
                var yy_options = "";
                for (ii=curyear; ii < curyear+10; ii++) {
                    yy_options = yy_options + '<option value="' + ii + '">' + ii + '</option>';
                }
                if ($("#date_format").val() == "date") {
                    str = str + '<span><select id="field_' + element_idx + '_0 style="width:3em">' + mm_options + '</select> / <label>MM</label></span>';
                    str = str + '<span><select id="field_' + element_idx + '_1 style="width:3em">' + dd_options + '</select> / <label>DD</label></span>';
                    str = str + '<span><select id="field_' + element_idx + '_2 style="width:5em">' + yy_options + '</select> <label>YYYY</label></span>';
                }
                else if ($("#date_format").val()  == "europe_date") {
                    str = str + '<span><select id="field_' + element_idx + '_1 style="width:3em">' + dd_options + '</select> / <label>DD</label></span>';
                    str = str + '<span><select id="field_' + element_idx + '_0 style="width:3em">' + mm_options + '</select> / <label>MM</label></span>';
                    str = str + '<span><select id="field_' + element_idx + '_2 style="width:5em">' + yy_options + '</select> <label>YYYY</label></span>';
                }
                else {
                    str = str + '<span><select id="field_' + element_idx + '_2 style="width:5em">' + yy_options + '</select> - <label>YYYY</label></span>';
                    str = str + '<span><select id="field_' + element_idx + '_0 style="width:3em">' + mm_options + '</select> - <label>MM</label></span>';
                    str = str + '<span><select id="field_' + element_idx + '_1 style="width:3em">' + dd_options + '</select> <label>DD</label></span>';
                }
            }
            else {
                if ($("#date_format").val() == "date") {
                    str = str + '<span><input type="text" size="2" id="field_' + element_idx + '_0' + '" class="text" readonly="readonly"/> / <label>MM</label></span>';
                    str = str + '<span><input type="text" size="2" id="field_' + element_idx + '_1' + '" class="text" readonly="readonly"/> / <label>DD</label></span>';
                    str = str + '<span><input type="text" size="4" id="field_' + element_idx + '_2' + '" class="text" readonly="readonly"/> <label>YYYY</label></span>';
                }
                else if ($("#date_format").val()  == "europe_date") {
                    str = str + '<span><input type="text" size="2" id="field_' + element_idx + '_1' + '" class="text" readonly="readonly"/> / <label>DD</label></span>';
                    str = str + '<span><input type="text" size="2" id="field_' + element_idx + '_0' + '" class="text" readonly="readonly"/> / <label>MM</label></span>';
                    str = str + '<span><input type="text" size="4" id="field_' + element_idx + '_2' + '" class="text" readonly="readonly"/> <label>YYYY</label></span>';
                }
                else {
                    str = str + '<span><input type="text" size="4" id="field_' + element_idx + '_2' + '" class="text" readonly="readonly"/> <label>YYYY</label></span>';
                    str = str + '<span><input type="text" size="2" id="field_' + element_idx + '_0' + '" class="text" readonly="readonly"/> - <label>MM</label></span>';
                    str = str + '<span><input type="text" size="2" id="field_' + element_idx + '_1' + '" class="text" readonly="readonly"/> - <label>DD</label></span>';
                }
            }
            str = str + '</div>';
            str = str + '</a>';
            $("li.current_edit a").replaceWith(str);
        }
        else if (inputtype == "time") {
            // str = hh(format,period),mm(format,period),ss(format,period)
            str = $("#hour_format").val() + "|" + $("#hour_period").val() + ",";
            str = str + $("#minute_format").val() + "|" + $("#minute_period").val() + ",";
            // str = str + $("#second_format").val() + "|" + $("#second_period").val();
            $("li.current_edit :input#format_" + input_id).val( str );

            var str = '<a title="Click to edit. Drag to reorder." onclick="return false;" class="hover_ready" href="#">';
            str = str + '<label id="title_' + input_id + '" class="desc">' + label + '</label>';
            str = str + '<div>';

            if ($("#hour_format").val() == "select") {
                str = str + '<span><select style="width: 6em;" id="field_' + input_id + '_0' + '" class="select">';
                if ($("#hour_period").val() == 12) {
                    str = str + '<option value="1AM">1 AM</option>';
                    str = str + '<option value="2AM">2 AM</option>';
                    str = str + '<option value="1PM"> .. </option>';
                    str = str + '<option value="1PM">12 PM</option>';
                }
                else if ($("#hour_period").val() == 24) {
                    str = str + '<option value="100">1</option>';
                    str = str + '<option value="200">2</option>';
                    str = str + '<option value="2300"> .. </option>';
                    str = str + '<option value="2400">24</option>';
                }
                str = str + '</select> : <label>HH</label></span>';
            }
            else {
                str = str + '<span><input type="text" size="2" id="field_' + input_id + '_0' + '" class="text" readonly="readonly"/> : <label>HH</label></span>';
            }

            if ($("#minute_format").val() == "select") {
                str = str + '<span><select style="width: 4em;" id="field_' + input_id + '_1' + '" class="select">';
                if ($("#minute_period").val() == 5) {
                    str = str + '<option value="0">0</option>';
                    str = str + '<option value="5">5</option>';
                    str = str + '<option value="50"> .. </option>';
                    str = str + '<option value="55">55</option>';
                }
                else if ($("#minute_period").val() == 10) {
                    str = str + '<option value="0">0</option>';
                    str = str + '<option value="10">10</option>';
                    str = str + '<option value="40"> .. </option>';
                    str = str + '<option value="50">50</option>';
                }
                else if ($("#minute_period").val() == 15) {
                    str = str + '<option value="0">0</option>';
                    str = str + '<option value="15">15</option>';
                    str = str + '<option value="30">30</option>';
                    str = str + '<option value="45">45</option>';
                }
                str = str + '</select> <label>MM</label></span>';
            }
            else {
                str = str + '<span><input type="text" size="2" id="field_' + input_id + '_1' + '" class="text" readonly="readonly"/> : <label>MM</label></span>';
            }
            /*
            if ($("#second_format").val() == "select") {
                str = str + '<span><select style="width: 4em;" id="field_' + input_id + '_2' + '" class="select">';
                str = str + '<option value="0">0</option>';
                str = str + '<option value="30">30</option>';
                str = str + '</select><label>SS</label></span>';
            }
            else {
                str = str + '<span><input type="text" size="2" id="field_' + input_id + '_2' + '" class="text" readonly="readonly"/><label>SS</label></span>';
            }
            */
            str = str + '</div>';
            str = str + '</a>';
            $("li.current_edit a").replaceWith(str);
        }
        else if (inputtype == "address") {
            $("li.current_edit :input#format_" + input_id).val($("#address_format").val());
            var str = "";
            if ($("#address_format").val() == "us") {
                str = '<div class="right" id="field_' + input_id + '_state">';
                str = str + '<select id="field_' + element_idx + '_3" class="select medium" >';
                str = str + '<option value="AL">Alaska</option>';
                str = str + '</select><label>State</label>';
                str = str + '</div>';
            }
            else {
                str = '<div class="right" id="field_' + input_id + '_state">';
                str = str + '<input type="text" id="field_' + element_idx + '_3" class="text medium" readonly="readonly"/><label>Province / Region</label>';
                str = str + '</div>';
            }
            $("div#field_" + input_id + "_state").replaceWith(str);
        }
        else if (inputtype == "phone") {
            $("li.current_edit a div span").remove();
            var str = "";
            if ($("#phone_format").val() == "us_phone") {
                $("li.current_edit :input#format_" + input_id).val("us_phone");
                str = '<span><input type="text" size="3" class="text" id="field_' + element_idx + '_0' + '" readonly="readonly"/> - <label>(###)</label></span>';
                str = str + '<span><input type="text" size="3" class="text" id="field_' + element_idx + '_1' + '" readonly="readonly"/> - <label>###</label></span>';
                str = str + '<span><input type="text" size="4" class="text" id="field_' + element_idx + '_2' + '" readonly="readonly"/><label>####</label></span>';
                $("li.current_edit a div:first").append(str);
            }
            else {
                $("li.current_edit :input#format_" + input_id).val("international");
                str = str + '<span><input type="text" size="20" class="text" id="field_' + element_idx + '_0' + '" readonly="readonly"/></span>';
                $("li.current_edit a div:first").append(str);
            }
        }
        else if ( inputtype == "text" || inputtype == "textarea" || inputtype == "website" || inputtype == "email" || inputtype == "file") {
            size = $("#element_properties").find("#element_size").val();
            $("li.current_edit :input#size_" + input_id).val(size);
            $("li.current_edit :input").removeClass("small");
            $("li.current_edit :input").removeClass("medium");
            $("li.current_edit :input").removeClass("large");
            $("li.current_edit :input").addClass($("#element_size").val());
        }
        else if (inputtype == "radio" || inputtype == "checkbox" || inputtype == "select") {
            var result_str = "";
            if (inputtype == "select")  $("li.current_edit select").children().remove();
            else    $("li.current_edit span:children").children().remove();
            $("ul#element_choices li").each( function(i, ob) {
                chkchk = "";
                sel = "";
                result_str = result_str + $(ob).find(":input#choice_" + i + "_name").val() + '|';
                result_str = result_str + $(ob).find(":input#choice_" + i + "_value").val() + '|';

                if ($(ob).find("img.option_default").length > 0) {
                    result_str = result_str + 'default|';
                    chkchk = "checked";
                    sel = "selected";
                }
                else {
                    result_str = result_str + '0|';
                }

                if (inputtype == "radio") {
                    str = '<input type="radio" id="field_' + input_id + '_' + i + '" name="' + name + '" class="radio" ' + chkchk + ' /><label class="choice">' + $(ob).find(":input").val() + '</label>';
                    $("li.current_edit span").append(str);
                }
                else if (inputtype == "checkbox") {
                    str = '<input type="checkbox" id="field_' + input_id + '_' + i + '" name="' + name + '" class="checkbox" ' + chkchk + ' /><label class="choice">' + $(ob).find(":input").val() + '</label>';
                    $("li.current_edit span").append(str);
                }
                else if (inputtype == "select") {
                    str = '<option ' + sel + ' >' + $(ob).find(":input").val() + '</option>';
                    $("li.current_edit :input#field_" + input_id).append(str);
                }
            });
            $("input#options_"+input_id).val(result_str);
        }
        else if (inputtype == "states") {
            str = $("#state_format").val();
            $("li.current_edit :input#format_" + input_id).val( str );
        }
        else if (inputtype == "countries") {
            str = $("#country_format").val();
            $("li.current_edit :input#format_" + input_id).val( str );
        }
        else if (inputtype == "sectionstart" || inputtype == "sectionheader" || inputtype == "sectionend") {
            $("li.current_edit :input#masterid_" + input_id).val('0');
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Way way to much code for us to go through. Set a break point and walk through the code and figure out where it is breaking.

Comment: That is actually where it is breaking .... the console doesnt give me a line though ...

Comment: That function is *ridiculous*; completely unmaintainable.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `label`, which is an HTML reserved word, as a variable name in your `else` statement.  Try changing that to some other name and see what happens.

Comment: it still gives me the same error .. with the name label still

Comment: JavaScript isn't HTML, also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Comment: Did you change the variable and all of the places that it is used?  Since `label` is used heavily in your code, you'll have to look at each one to make sure you changed all of the correct ones.

Comment: @DaveNewton - I'm trying to guide the OP toward a step by step debugging process rather than parsing the entire method on my own (since it is ridiculously huge).  Change the places where the OP is using the reserved word and see if that changes the error.  If not, then at least once possibility has been eliminated.

Comment: @TLS It's not a reserved word. (Or if it is, show me the docs--I've provided some evidence it isn't.)

Comment: @DaveNewton - feel free to edit my answer with the correct terminology.  It's not reserved in JavaScript, but it is a special word in HTML.

Comment: @TLS The issue isn't in HTML, but in JavaScript. Specifically, most likely, a jQuery selector.